How to render state changes when state is an array in NextJS?
In the following example, I use the useState hook to keep track of a variable, an array is what causes the unwanted behavior. For simplicity, that variable holds a boolean value. When I update the state with the setState function, the state changes and is reflected in the proceeding call to console.log. However, the change of state is not rendered.
Here's the example of code that causes the issue:
"use client"

import { useState } from "react"

export default function Example() {
  const [state, setState] = useState<boolean[]>([false, false])

  const changeState = () => {
    setState((s) => {
      s[0] = !s[0]
      return s
    })
    console.log("state set to", state)
  }

  return (
    <button className="w-12 h-4 text-white" onClick={changeState}>
      {`${state}`}
    </button>
  )
}

Am I using incorrect syntax/procedure to update the state or is this unintended behavior? Is there a way around this situation?
Note: It's necessary that the state variable is a dynamically allocated container since I will not know how many elements to keep track of beforehand.

Problem :

State not updating on screen, despite being updated in console.log

Possible Causes :

React ignores, a mutated object(state) which is passed back to setState

Possible Solution :
React recommends replacing Objects & Array datatypes state.
setState((s) => {
    s[0] = !s[0]
    return [...s]
})

Further this can be improved (will make accessing a variable more accurate & easy even if amount of them increases var3, var4 ...):
const [Variables, setVariables] = useState({ var1: false, var2: false })

Change State by :
setVariables({ ...Variables, var1: !Variables.var1 })
// other variables remain unchanged, because we overwritten var1

Please Read :

I’ve updated the state, but the screen doesn’t update : https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-the-screen-doesnt-update


If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)


Setting state with [...s] solves my issue. I'm assuming React is using an object ID or pointer to determine if the state has changed, and that doesn't change in the example implementation. Thanks!
